# Difference between asfreq and resample

Tags: python, pandas

Can some please explain the difference between the asfreq and resample methods in pandas? When should one use what?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let me use an example to illustrate:

```
# generate a series of 365 days
# index = 20190101, 20190102, ... 20191231
# values = [0,1,...364]
ts = pd.Series(range(365), index = pd.date_range(start='20190101', 
                                                end='20191231',
                                                freq = 'D'))
ts.head()

output:
2019-01-01    0
2019-01-02    1
2019-01-03    2
2019-01-04    3
2019-01-05    4
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Now, resample the data by quarter:

```
ts.asfreq(freq='Q')

output:
2019-03-31     89
2019-06-30    180
2019-09-30    272
2019-12-31    364
Freq: Q-DEC, dtype: int64
```

The `asfreq()` returns a `Series` object with the last day of each quarter in it.

```
ts.resample('Q')

output:
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<QuarterEnd: startingMonth=12>, axis=0, closed=right, label=right, convention=start, base=0]
```

Resample returns a `DatetimeIndexResampler` and you cannot see what's actually inside. Think of it as the `groupby` method. It creates a list of `bins` (groups):

```
bins = ts.resample('Q')
bin.groups

output:
 {Timestamp('2019-03-31 00:00:00', freq='Q-DEC'): 90,
 Timestamp('2019-06-30 00:00:00', freq='Q-DEC'): 181,
 Timestamp('2019-09-30 00:00:00', freq='Q-DEC'): 273,
 Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00', freq='Q-DEC'): 365}
```

Nothing seems different so far except for the return type. Let's calculate the average of each quarter:

```
# (89+180+272+364)/4 = 226.25
ts.asfreq(freq='Q').mean()

output:
226.25
```

When `mean()` is applied, it outputs the average of all the values. Note that this is not the average of each quarter, but the average of the last day of each quarter.

To calculate the average of each quarter:

```
ts.resample('Q').mean()

output:
2019-03-31     44.5
2019-06-30    135.0
2019-09-30    226.5
2019-12-31    318.5
```

[You can perform more powerful operations with `resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) than `asfreq()`.

Think of `resample` as `groupby` + every method that you can call after `groupby` (e.g. mean, sum, apply, you name it) .

Think of `asfreq` as a filter mechanism with limited `fillna()` capabilities (in fillna(), you can specify `limit`, but asfreq() does not support it).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the thought process behind the naming convention here? It seems backward, in my opinion.

Answer (score 46):

`resample` is more general than `asfreq`. For example, using `resample` I can pass an arbitrary function to perform binning over a `Series` or `DataFrame` object in bins of arbitrary size. `asfreq` is a concise way of changing the frequency of a `DatetimeIndex` object. It also provides padding functionality.

As the pandas documentation says, `asfreq` is a thin wrapper around a call to `date_range` + a call to `reindex`. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#frequency-conversion) for an example.

An example of `resample` that I use in my daily work is computing the number of spikes of a neuron in 1 second bins by resampling a large boolean array where `True` means "spike" and `False` means "no spike". I can do that as easy as `large_bool.resample('S', how='sum')`. Kind of neat!

`asfreq` can be used when you want to change a `DatetimeIndex` to have a different frequency while retaining the same values at the current index.

Here's an example where they are equivalent:

```
In [6]: dr = date_range('1/1/2010', periods=3, freq=3 * datetools.bday)

In [7]: raw = randn(3)

In [8]: ts = Series(raw, index=dr)

In [9]: ts
Out[9]:
2010-01-01   -1.948
2010-01-06    0.112
2010-01-11   -0.117
Freq: 3B, dtype: float64

In [10]: ts.asfreq(datetools.BDay())
Out[10]:
2010-01-01   -1.948
2010-01-04      NaN
2010-01-05      NaN
2010-01-06    0.112
2010-01-07      NaN
2010-01-08      NaN
2010-01-11   -0.117
Freq: B, dtype: float64

In [11]: ts.resample(datetools.BDay())
Out[11]:
2010-01-01   -1.948
2010-01-04      NaN
2010-01-05      NaN
2010-01-06    0.112
2010-01-07      NaN
2010-01-08      NaN
2010-01-11   -0.117
Freq: B, dtype: float64
```

As far as when to use either: it depends on the problem you have in mind...care to share?

Comment: So actually `asfreq` is a true resampling recreating a value from local values (maybe by interpolation), as required by the new sampling interval, while `resample` actually only creates a sets of samples (bins), to which any operation can be applied, like `mean` to substitute a new value for each set. Quite a misnomer.

Comment: @mins I think that's it... So `resample` doesn't resample, it groups data by a given periodicity.  `asfreq` actually resamples data. The naming convention is a bit of a shame... But at least there are two functions that actually do both things even if their names are backward.