# Fill datetimeindex gap by NaN

Tags: python, pandas, reindex, gaps-in-data, datetimeindex

I have two dataframes which are datetimeindexed. One is missing a few of these datetimes (`df1`) while the other is complete (has regular timestamps without any gaps in this series) and is full of `NaN`'s (`df2`).

I'm trying to match the values from df1 to the index of `df2`, filling with `NaN`'s where such a `datetimeindex` doesn't exist in `df1`.

Example:

```
In  [51]: df1
Out [51]:                       value
          2015-01-01 14:00:00   20
          2015-01-01 15:00:00   29
          2015-01-01 16:00:00   41
          2015-01-01 17:00:00   43
          2015-01-01 18:00:00   26
          2015-01-01 19:00:00   20
          2015-01-01 20:00:00   31
          2015-01-01 21:00:00   35
          2015-01-01 22:00:00   39
          2015-01-01 23:00:00   17
          2015-03-01 00:00:00   6
          2015-03-01 01:00:00   37
          2015-03-01 02:00:00   56
          2015-03-01 03:00:00   12
          2015-03-01 04:00:00   41
          2015-03-01 05:00:00   31
          ...   ...

          2018-12-25 23:00:00   41

          <34843 rows × 1 columns>

In  [52]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=pd.date_range(freq='60Min', start=df1.index.min(), end=df1.index.max()))
          df2['value']=np.NaN
          df2
Out [52]:                       value
          2015-01-01 14:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 15:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 16:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 17:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 18:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 19:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 20:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 21:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 22:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-01 23:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 00:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 01:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 02:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 03:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 04:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 05:00:00   NaN
          ...                   ...
          2018-12-25 23:00:00   NaN

          <34906 rows × 1 columns>
```

Using `df2.combine_first(df1)` returns the same data as `df1.reindex(index= df2.index)`, which fills any gaps where there shouldn't be data with some value, instead of NaN.

```
In  [53]: Result = df2.combine_first(df1)
          Result
Out [53]:                       value
          2015-01-01 14:00:00   20
          2015-01-01 15:00:00   29
          2015-01-01 16:00:00   41
          2015-01-01 17:00:00   43
          2015-01-01 18:00:00   26
          2015-01-01 19:00:00   20
          2015-01-01 20:00:00   31
          2015-01-01 21:00:00   35
          2015-01-01 22:00:00   39
          2015-01-01 23:00:00   17
          2015-01-02 00:00:00   35
          2015-01-02 01:00:00   53
          2015-01-02 02:00:00   28
          2015-01-02 03:00:00   48
          2015-01-02 04:00:00   42
          2015-01-02 05:00:00   51
          ...                   ...
          2018-12-25 23:00:00   41

          <34906 rows × 1 columns>
```

This is what I was hoping to get:

```
Out [53]:                       value
          2015-01-01 14:00:00   20
          2015-01-01 15:00:00   29
          2015-01-01 16:00:00   41
          2015-01-01 17:00:00   43
          2015-01-01 18:00:00   26
          2015-01-01 19:00:00   20
          2015-01-01 20:00:00   31
          2015-01-01 21:00:00   35
          2015-01-01 22:00:00   39
          2015-01-01 23:00:00   17
          2015-01-02 00:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 01:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 02:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 03:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 04:00:00   NaN
          2015-01-02 05:00:00   NaN
          ...                   ...
          2018-12-25 23:00:00   41

          <34906 rows × 1 columns>
```

Could someone shed some light on why this is happening, and how to set how these values are filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) `df1`, because you have an irregular `frequency` and you need regular frequency:

```
print df1.index.freq
None

print Result.index.freq
<60 * Minutes>
```

**EDIT1**
You can use function [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) instead of `resample` - [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#frequency-conversion), [`resample vs asfreq`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060619/difference-between-asfreq-and-resample).

**EDIT2**
First I think that `resample` didn't work, because after resampling the `Result` is the same as `df1`. But I try `print df1.info()` and `print Result.info()` gets different results - `34857 entries` vs `34920 entries`. 
So I try to find rows with `NaN` values and it returns `63 rows`.

So I think `resample` works well.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test/GapInTimestamps.csv', sep=",", index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
print df1.head()

#                     value
#Date/Time                 
#2015-01-01 00:00:00     52
#2015-01-01 01:00:00      5
#2015-01-01 02:00:00     12
#2015-01-01 03:00:00     54
#2015-01-01 04:00:00     47
print df1.info()

#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#DatetimeIndex: 34857 entries, 2015-01-01 00:00:00 to 2018-12-25 23:00:00
#Data columns (total 1 columns):
#value    34857 non-null int64
#dtypes: int64(1)
#memory usage: 544.6 KB
#None

Result  = df1.resample('60min')
print Result.head()

#                     value
#Date/Time                 
#2015-01-01 00:00:00     52
#2015-01-01 01:00:00      5
#2015-01-01 02:00:00     12
#2015-01-01 03:00:00     54
#2015-01-01 04:00:00     47
print Result.info()

#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#DatetimeIndex: 34920 entries, 2015-01-01 00:00:00 to 2018-12-25 23:00:00
#Freq: 60T
#Data columns (total 1 columns):
#value    34857 non-null float64
#dtypes: float64(1)
#memory usage: 545.6 KB
#None

#find values with NaN
resultnan =  Result[Result.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

```
#temporaly display 999 rows and 15 columns
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 999, 'display.max_columns', 15):
    print resultnan

#                     value
#Date/Time                 
#2015-01-13 19:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-13 20:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-13 21:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-13 22:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-13 23:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 00:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 01:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 02:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 03:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 04:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 05:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 06:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 07:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 08:00:00    NaN
#2015-01-14 09:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 00:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 01:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 02:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 03:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 04:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 05:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 06:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 07:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 08:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 09:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 10:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 11:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 12:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 13:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 14:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 15:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 16:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 17:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 18:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 19:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 20:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 21:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 22:00:00    NaN
#2015-02-01 23:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 00:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 01:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 02:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 03:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 04:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 05:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 06:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 07:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 08:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 09:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 10:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 11:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 12:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 13:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 14:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 15:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 16:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 17:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 18:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 19:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 20:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 21:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 22:00:00    NaN
#2015-11-01 23:00:00    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jezrael, I've tried your method, but still have the same issue using `asfreq` or `resample`. The gaps filled in to make the series regular contain data that shouldn't be there. There are other holes in the index which might have some effect. If it helps, I'm using pandas version 0.14.1 and python 2.7.10

Comment: I added my testing data, still same problem? If yes, it can be your version 0.14.1 - I use 0.17.1 and it works well.

Comment: I've updated pandas to 0.17.1 and used your testing data to get the same result you did. Using my data still fills in the *new* datetimeindexes with data. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B82MDyNXtwwwZzJ2X2xOTmdnZjQ/view?usp=sharing)  is a link to the csv where my data is stored - perhaps you'll get the same issue I'm having with this?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. You've made it clear for me to see that `resample` was working. This made me look closer at my data-set to see that Pandas was interpreting the date differently to how i expected. The data was in _day/month/year hour:minute_ - whereas Pandas was seeing this as _month/day/year hour:minute_. I've included a `dayfirst=True` in the `pd.read_csv` and its working exactly I expected it to now. Thanks for all your help!