# pandas GroupBy on the index and find the max

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataframe (around 35k entries), the index of this data frame is composed by dates (like `2014-02-12`), this dates are not unique. What I need to do is to find for each data what is the **max value**  for each data and create a new data frame with it. I created a solution that works (it is down bellow) but it takes a lot of time to process. Does anyone knows a faster way that I could do this? Thank you.

```
#Creates a empty dataframe
dataset0514maxrec = pd.DataFrame(columns=dataset0514max.columns.values)
dataset0514maxrec.index.name = 'Date'

#Gets the unique values, find the groups, recover the max value and append it
for i in dataset0514max.index.unique():
    tempDF1 = dataset0514max.loc[dataset0514max.index.isin([i])]
    tempDF2 = tempDF1[tempDF1['Data_Value'] == tempDF1['Data_Value'].max()]
    dataset0514maxrec = dataset0514maxrec.append(tempDF2.head(1))

print(dataset0514maxrec)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `groupby` with `levels`

```
df.groupby(level=0).Data_Value.max().reset_index()
```

---

> The next two options require the index to be a `datetime` index. If it
>   isn't, convert it:
>
> ```
> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
> ```

#### `resample`

```
df.resample('D').max()
```

---

#### `sort_values` + `duplicated`

```
df = df.sort_values('Data_Value')
m = ~df.index.duplicated()
df = df[m]
```

Comment: It worked so perfectly, just wanted to know something. what does `level=0` means?

Comment: @FilipeLemos It groups by the index (`level=0` implies that it should take the index. Usually, index has only one level -> level 0. Multiindex has more levels, in which case, you specify level = 0, level = 1, or similar.)

Comment: `df.resample('D').max()` ... But requires that daily is ok

Comment: @FilipeLemos Please try option 2 and option 3 and let me know if those work as well.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, trying to learn the difference between resample and asfreq, any ideas?

Comment: @Vaishali Hah! Speaking of, an exact such question was once asked :D Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060619/difference-between-asfreq-and-resample

Comment: I read that before asking this question. Not much there, is it?:)

Comment: @Vaishali Yeah, pandas is guilty of having some underwhelming documentation sometimes. Another example is their json_normalize function. Very useful, yet very esoteric.

Comment: One more option `df.reset_index().sort_values('Data_Value').drop_duplicates('index')`

Comment: @Wen Nice one! I improved upon it slightly using `duplicated` so that reset_index is not required.

Comment: Ok `dataset2015max.resample('D').max()` worked perfectly but the `asfreq` returned a error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. The `resample` solution returns a **Dataframe** and the `groupby` returns a **Series**.