# How to convert data into time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have : (dateTime is in string format)

```
df
dateTime                  level  
2020-10-31T23:18:00.000   slow     
2020-10-31T23:25:00.000   moderate
```

I want to convert this to time series in 1min level by replicating the 'level' for every minute until the next instance where there is a change:

```
df
dateTime                level   
2020-10-31 23:18:00     slow      
2020-10-31 23:19:00     slow
2022-10-31 23:20:00     slow
......
2020-10-31 23:25:00     moderate     
2022-10-31 23:26:00     moderate
```

How do I, first convert the string dateTime format into datetime dtype, and convert the dataframe into time series?

Answer (score 1):

Create `DatetimeIndex` and use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df['dateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime'])
df = df.set_index('dateTime').asfreq('1Min', method='ffill')
print (df)
                        level
dateTime                     
2020-10-31 23:18:00      slow
2020-10-31 23:19:00      slow
2020-10-31 23:20:00      slow
2020-10-31 23:21:00      slow
2020-10-31 23:22:00      slow
2020-10-31 23:23:00      slow
2020-10-31 23:24:00      slow
2020-10-31 23:25:00  moderate
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like `resample` to do that. Resample has the advantage to produce "even" results (e.g. full minutes), while `asfreq` would keep seconds. [More info on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060619/difference-between-asfreq-and-resample)

More info on [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.fillna.html?highlight=resampler%20fillna#pandas.core.resample.Resampler.fillna) methods

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
dateTime level
2020-10-31T23:18:00.000 slow
2020-10-31T23:25:00.000 moderate
'''), sep=" ") #  , infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates=["dateTime"], index_col="dateTime"

df.dateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.dateTime) # string to datetime

df = df.set_index('dateTime') # datetime index needed for resample

df = df.resample("1min").fillna("pad") # use strings like '1h'
```

Produces:

| dateTime | level |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-10-31 23:18:00 | slow |
| 2020-10-31 23:19:00 | slow |
| 2020-10-31 23:20:00 | slow |
| 2020-10-31 23:21:00 | slow |
| 2020-10-31 23:22:00 | slow |
| 2020-10-31 23:23:00 | slow |
| 2020-10-31 23:24:00 | slow |
| 2020-10-31 23:25:00 | moderate |

You can also do the conversion of datetime and set index while reading:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
dateTime level
2020-10-31T23:18:00.000 slow
2020-10-31T23:25:00.000 moderate
'''), sep=" ", infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates=["dateTime"], index_col="dateTime")
```